# How to use raw pointers recursively from unique pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, raw-pointer

I am attempting to create an AVL tree with unique pointers. But I am stuck on the elementary part of inserting nodes recursively. This code creates a segmentation fault at the call to the `insertNode_` function. I thought that merely passing raw pointers would work, but it does not.

```
#ifndef AVL_H
#define AVL_H
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>



template<class T>
class AVL
{
  public:
    template<class K,class V>
    struct nodeAVL;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<nodeAVL<int,T>> node_ptr;
    typedef nodeAVL<int,T> node;

  /* Node struct */
    template<class K,class V>
    struct nodeAVL
    {
      nodeAVL(const K& key, const V& value):
           key_ (key), value_ (value)
          { left = nullptr;right=nullptr;parent=nullptr; }
      std::unique_ptr< nodeAVL<K,V> > left, right;
          node*  parent;
      V value()
           { return value_; }
      K key()
           { return key_; }
      K key(const K& key)
           { key_ = key; }
      private:
        K key_;
        V value_;
    };
 /* end of Node struct  */


    AVL()
        { head_=nullptr; };
    void insert (const T& value)
        { std::cout<<value<<" inserting\n";
          insertNode_ (head_, head_->parent,value); }
    std::string print() 
        { std::cout<<"print\n";
          return print_inOrder_(head_, ""); }

  private:
    node_ptr head_;

    template <class N, class... Args>  //allows make_unique in c11
    std::unique_ptr<N> make_unique(Args&&... args) {
    return std::unique_ptr<N>(new N(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}


 /* recursive insertion   */
    void insertNode_( node_ptr& current,node* parent, const T& value)
    {
      std::cout<<"segmentation fault happens here, this line doesnt print\n";
      if (current == nullptr){
        current = std::move(make_unique<node>(-1,value));
        std::cout<<current->value()<<" inserted\n";
        if (parent!= nullptr)
          std::cout<<"another issue happens here after root insertion\n";
      }
      else {
        if ( current->value() > value ) 
          insertNode_(current->left, current.get(),value);
        else if ( current->value() < value )
          insertNode_(current->right, current.get(),value);
      }
    }



 /* recursive inOrder print  */
    std::string print_inOrder_(const node_ptr& current,std::string print)
    {
      if (current != nullptr) {
      std::cout<<"<"<<current->value()<<">"<<std::endl;
        print+= "[" + std::to_string(current->value())+"]";
        print = print_inOrder_(current->left,print);
        print = print_inOrder_(current->right,print);
      }
      return print;
    }

};

#endif
```

Comment: It has to be the caller with the fault; best guess is here:  `insertNode_ (head_, head_->parent,value);` head is null.  Put a breakpoint on this line and inspect the values.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! THAT solved my issue. I changed  `head->parent` to `nullptr` and now it works.